# Corrected scalable structure for a big RESTful API with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, architecture, scalability

I need to create a large server with node.js that is as scalable as possible and suitable for serious production. In my project, I'm also using typescript to make sure my app is as scalable as possible

I have seen surfing the internet that virtually all projects are structured by grouping files for their purpose/role. Instead of all these articles, I read only twice the recommendation to structure the app with autonomous components.

So what is the best structure for great scalability?

```
└───src
    ├───bin
    ├───components
    │   ├───Auth
    │   ├───Post
    │   ├───Profile
    │   └───User
    ├───config
    │   └───keys
    └───database
```

or

```
└───src
    ├───config
    │   └───components
    ├───controllers
    ├───models
    │   └───plugins
    ├───routes
    │   └───api
    ├───utils
    └───validation
        └───forms
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the second one, because it separates better your code and makes it more readable. You should also consider making a tests folder and a .env file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then what do you think on the first point of this [guide](https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices)?

Comment: It all depends on you, I prefer the second because it separates what are the models the controllers and the database. If you try c# or spring (java) you will see that's how the projects are structured so now I always develop like that. I think both approaches are valid, in the end, it relies on your taste